# Get project version from svn (VisualSVN) repository using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, ajax, svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

Save your data in the repository at VisualSVN
https://myserver.ru:8443/svn/my-repository/my-project

Can I get the current version of the project in SVN using php or javascript (javascript (jQuery, Ajax etc) is preferable)?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention php I thought that you may also use js on the server (node). If this is the case, this module can help:

https://github.com/ddliu/node-svn-spawn

This is a sample response from a getstatus command:

```
[
  {
    "$": {
      "path": "a.txt"
    },
    "wc-status": {
      "$": {
        "props": "none",
        "item": "modified",
        "revision": "1"
      },
      "commit": {
        "$": {
          "revision": "1"
        },
        "author": "dong",
        "date": "2013-11-08T02:17:20.390152Z"
      }
    }
  }
]
```